# Github multiple accounts - Permission to personalUserName/repoName.git denied to globalUserName

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

**Update 5/14/2018**
I updated my OS and had to reboot my machine, so this apparently messed up my fix to this issue, which seems to have been temporary. To temporarily fix this again, I had to do the following:

1. ran `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`
2. `ssh-add ~/.ssh/your-ssh-key`
3. enter you ssh key passsphrase
4. run any git command you want

I need to look into making this permanent. It is definitely related to me commenting out the `Host *` section from my .ssh/config file, so I need to figure out how to use keychain for some and not all hosts, since all hosts is not working for my setup.

**Update 5/2/2018:**

In case anyone has this issue, I used the output of `ssh -vT git@github.com` to find where the configuration was being picked up from and this lead me to do a few things to fix my issue:

1. removed `name` value from my `.gitconfig` found in my root folder `~`
2. as shown above, I had a section in my `.ssh/config` file for `Host *` which I commented out
3. confirmed that `git config user.name` and `git config user.email` were set correctly for the specific repo I was working on
4. confirmed my remote repo was set properly, e.g. `git remote set-url origin git@github-newkeyname:repo_git_target`

Thanks.

---

I have a work and a personal GitHub account and recently wanted to work on my personal account. However, I kept getting an error message saying

`Permission to personalUserName/repoName.git denied to globalUserName`

I looked up how to work with multiple GitHub accounts and found this tutorial - https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574

I followed all the instructions and finally added the remote using the new key, as described in the tutorial, e.g.

`git remote add origin git@github-newkeyname:username/repoName.git`

When I try to push from my local project to my personal GitHub repo, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Permission to localUserName/repoName.git denied to globalUserName.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The one thing I notice here is that the `localUserName/repoName.git` includes the local username I added with `git config user.name`, and the error shows that permission was denied to the username added (a long time ago) with `git config --global user.name`.

I am unsure if the issue is related to the SSH keys or to the git config, or both. Does anyone have any suggestions?

When I test my SSH connection with `ssh -vT git@github-newkeyname` and `ssh -vT git@github`, I see both authenticating with the same username, in this case, that which I call the globalUserName, i.e.

```
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi globalUserName! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

This is what my SSH config file looks like at the relevant places:

```
94 Host *
95 UseKeychain yes
96 AddKeysToAgent yes
97 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/someFile.pem
98
99 Host github-newkeyname
100 Hostname github.com
101 User git
102 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_newkeyname
103 IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Comment: This is a useful question and your edits helped me (thanks!), but feedback in terms of "good stackoverflow practice": rather than modifying your own question with updates, just answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - whereby after changing my local repo's config, commits/pushes were still being registered to my *old* user, which didn't have repo access (the repo was created by my *new* user identity).

The issue wasn't that my old ('global') user was still being assigned to **new** commits - rather, that user was still connected to the **old** commits (prior to updating my `./git/config`, and my SSH wasn't setup correctly.

I solved this by:

1. (Assuming this is done already, but:) Setting a repo-specific `user` & `email` within `./git/config`
2. Making sure my ssh key was active for this new github identity, `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa_newkeyname`
3. Restarting my computer (probably totally superfluous, but just in case it's important)
4. Pushing my staged changes to the repo (these changes were associated to my `global-user`, as I made them *before* changing my `./git/config` user settings, but the correct addition of my other ssh key allowed the push to go ahead
5. Once done, stage & commit as normal - all of which are being assigned to the new github identity :party: